# Design pattern for multiple services

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

What pattern(s) would be good to manage multiple API's?

A scenario for using multiple API's would be a payment portal that allows clients to use different payment vendors to post transactions.  So this system may need to utilize a papypal, fasttransact, x, y, or z API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want a unique [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) interface of your design, bridging your calls to each of these different payment vendors' systems; the concrete realizations of that Facade will likely be implemented, of course, by what amounts to a collection of [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)s -- and the appropriate one for a given transaction can be chosen by some appropriate [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (method or otherwise;-).